# Find specific element in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

I have an array A containing n arrays. Each of the n arrays, contains two element. The first is an id, while the second is an object. For more details, see the following example:

```
A = [ [100, object1], [22, object2], [300, object3]]
```

For a given id, I want to get the associated object. Example, for `id = 22`, I want to get `object2`.

Comment: Can you use underscore.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop, check, and return

```
function getById(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i][0] == id) {
            return A[i][1];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am currently using `Coffeescript`

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic way of doing it. Iterate over `A`, keep checking whether the first member of each array matches your id, and return the associated object in case of a match.

```
function returnObjectById(id) {
    for (var i=0; i< A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i][0]==id) {
            return A[i][1];
        }
    }
    return false; // in case id does not exist
}
```

In Coffeescript:

```
returnObjectById = (id) ->
  i = 0
  while i < A.length
    if A[i][0] == id
      return A[i][1]
    i++
  false
  # in case id does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

A CoffeeScript version could like:

```
find_in = (a, v) ->
    return e[1] for e in a when e[0] == v
```

then you could say:

```
thing = find_in(A, 22)
```

You'd get `undefined` if there was no `v` to be found.

The `for e in a` is a basic for-loop and then `when` clause only executes the body when its condition is true. So that loop is functionally equivalent to:

```
for e in a
    if e[0] == v
        return e[1]
```

The [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) covers all this.

Comment: When using for..in in older IEs, be aware that each Array has an additional indexOf member.

Comment: Can you explain this line of code: `return e[1] for e in a when e[0] == v` ?
Thanks

Comment: @connexo: CoffeeScript's `for e in array` is not the same as JavaScript's, JavaScript's `in` loop would be `for k of object` in CoffeeScript.

Answer (score -1):

In CoffeeScript you can use the [JS to CF transition](http://js2.coffee/)

```
getById = (id) ->
  i = 0
  while i < A.length
    if A[i][0] == id
      return A[i][1]
    i++
  false
```